# cardView icon and name alignment issue in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

i want to set icon with name in cardview . But unable to do this .

Alignment is not proper after use of this xml .

It should be like this image [image]

activity_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="Location" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/location"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#01458e"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deals"
                android:src="@drawable/deals"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location"
                android:text="Deals"

                />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location"
                android:layout_below="@+id/deals"
                android:text="Deals"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#01458e"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cuisine"
                android:src="@drawable/cuisine"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deals"
                android:text="Cuisine"
                />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cuisine"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cuisine"
                android:text="Cuisine"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#01458e"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


</LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting after using this like image which is below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. change images according to your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_big" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_eye" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Explore"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/location"
                    android:tint="@color/colorOrange" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/location"
                    android:tint="@color/colorOrange" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Deals"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/location"
                    android:tint="@color/colorOrange" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Cusine"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/car"
                    android:tint="@color/colorOrange" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Dive-in"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It Looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this xml instead of yours .............

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_image"
                android:src="@drawable/test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/whatsapp"
            android:text="Location" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/whatsapp"
            android:text="Deals"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lastimage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/whatsapp"
            android:text="Deals"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cuisine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/whatsapp"
            android:text="Cuisine" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Location"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#01458e"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Deals"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#01458e"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cuisine"
            android:textColor="#01458e"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="LastText"
            android:textColor="#01458e"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

           </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**Note:-change text and image according to you projects....**

you image look like these ........

[image: output]

enjoy coding........

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout, re-correct syntax where id=cusine, image should b

```
 width=80 and height=100.
```